# Algorithm for Variant of 0-1 Knapsack Problem

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, np-hard, knapsack-problems, parameterized-complexity

Variant of 0-1 Knapsack Problem is when you can choose exactly $k$ items from $n$ items, and $k$ is positive integer parameter that came in the input.
Is there an algorithm with running time complexity $f(k) \cdot n^{O(1)}$ when $f$ is some function of $k$ only without $n$ that solve the Variant of 0-1 Knapsack Problem?
In other words Is there an FPT algorithm for the problem?

Comment: Have you done any sort of literature review? For example, have you looked at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07724.pdf?

Comment: This is a variation  of multidimensional  0/1 knapsack  that at least hard as 2-d knapsack, so you can't find an algorithm that the running time  only depend on $k$, and $n$.